# Why is the database tab not functional in Crystal Reports 9?

Tags: odbc, database-administration, crystal-reports

I have a particular report that I can run, it prompts for an Oracle username and password and then generates the report. The Database tab is not fully available. I cannot select `Database Expert` or `set datasource`.

[image]

What is going on, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Have you confirmed the user you are using has the correct privileges to access those features?

Comment: How do I find out if I have the correct privileges?  To the report or the database?

Comment: I would suggest speaking to your database administrator or IT dept about your access levels.

Comment: I have admin privileges.